# how to bind array to multi Select Dropdown in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 2, want to bind Role of Employee to dropdown list which is multiselct. Already I have Roles in that dropdown which is fetched from database. 
If I click on edit employee button i want to bind Roles to that dropdown and show as which roles are selected. how to do this?

DropDown in html

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label>Employee Roles</label>
               <select id="dates-field2"  #role="ngModel" 
               style="height:200px;" name="Role" 
               class="multiselect-ui form-control" multiple="multiple" 
               [(ngModel)]="selectedRole" required >
              <option value="0">--Select--</option>
              <option *ngFor="let role of roles" value={{role.OID}}>
                    {{role.RollName}}
               </option>
         </select>
      </div>
```

Role Module

```
export class Role {
        OID: number;
        RollName: string;
        constructor(OID: number, RollName: string) {
              this.OID = OID;
              this.RollName = RollName;
       }
   }
```

.ts file

```
observableRole: Observable<Role[]>
roles: Role[];
OnEditingStart(value: any) { 
       //here I want to set values to dropdown.
       this.OID = value.data.OID;
       this.observableRole = this.employeeService.getEmployeeRole(this.OID);
       this.observableRole.subscribe(
       roles =>  this.roles = roles,
       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
       console.log(this.role);
 }
```

Comment: Please, show us code. Thank you

Comment: please check i updated my question

Comment: Maybe this will give some inspiration? https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2 - Googled on "Angular 2 Master/Detail"

Comment: Thank you but when i click on employee edit button want to show how many roles assign to that employee in dropdown list. so how can i bind that json to dropdown.  and my json for roles is like,                                  
[
{
"OID": 2,
"RollName": "Admin"
},
{
"OID": 3,
"RollName": "PM"
}]

Comment: [Asking a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In the code provided the `roles` array is bound to the options of the `select` dropdown... If it is not working as expected it is probably down to your implementation of your dropdown itself- here is one such implementation [multi select plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/5JuqBp?autoCloseSidebar&show=preview)

Comment: roles array is bound perfectly to dropdown.